# Регулярное выражение, удаляющее лишнюю запятую в числе

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Необходимо регулярное выражение удаляющее символ `,` в случае если он не стоит в конце строки перед двумя цифрами.

Например:

```
1000,00 --> 1000,00
1000,,00 --> 1000,00
10,00,00 --> 1000,00
10,0,000 --> 100000
```

Comment: @UModeL, добавил

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Используется *negative lookahead assertion* `(?!\d\d$)`.

```js
const text = `1000,00
1000,,00
10,00,00
10,0,000`;

console.log(text.replace(/,(?!\d\d$)/gm, ''));
```